# Apply EF (not EF core) to an ASP.NET Core project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Goal:

Use Entity Framework (not EF Core) in an ASP.NET Core project.

According to instruction you have to create a .net project and then you go to ASP.NET Core project and add it to references by selecting this EF project.
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6?view=aspnetcore-3.0#reference-full-framework-and-ef6-in-the-asp-net-core-project)

Problem: I get an error message

> Error CS0012  The type 'DbSet<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

I have already applied EF in the project but I still get this error.

I have also applied a github link that you can download the solution and its project
https://github.com/candyboyyy/ef

Info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6?view=aspnetcore-3.0#reference-full-framework-and-ef6-in-the-asp-net-core-project

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Blogs]
(
    [BlogId] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [NVARCHAR](200) NULL,
    [Url] [NVARCHAR](200) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Blogs] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BlogId] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: EF 6.3 supports.Net core 3, but not 2.2, you need to change your project to target netcoreapp3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ASP.NET Core `!=` .NET Core

ASP.NET Core can run on .NET Core or .NET Framework (See [Introduction to ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/index?view=aspnetcore-3.0)).

## EF Compatibility

### EF >= 6.3

From 6.3 EF supports .NET Core.

[Announcing Entity Framework 6.3 Preview with .NET Core Support](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-6-3-preview-with-net-core-support/)

> In fact, the main goal of this release is to facilitate migrating existing applications that use EF 6 to .NET Core 3.0.

### EF <6.3

If you want to use EF<6.3 from ASP.Core you need to target .NET framework. The following is from [Get Started with ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6?view=aspnetcore-3.0#reference-full-framework-and-ef6-in-the-aspnet-core-project).

> To use Entity Framework 6, your project has to compile against .NET Framework, as Entity Framework 6 doesn't support .NET Core.

## Your solution specifically

The library project in your solution needs to be converted to a .NET Core project.

Comment: I'm fully aware 'bout it but but the sample that I have created don't work.

Comment: Your app targets .Net Core and references at .net framework project. It won't work.

Comment: "In Package Manager Console (PMC) for both projects, run the command Install-Package Entityframework."   (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6?view=aspnetcore-3.0#reference-full-framework-and-ef6-in-the-aspnet-core-project)

Comment: Do you have any idea 'bout how to solve it? I mean concrete solution with c# code.

Comment: EF 6.3 now supports .Net Core 3/.Net Standard 2.1. It is no longer necessary to target .Net Framework if you wish to use full EF. The referenced article is no longer valid.